# How to write a function in SML/NJ that in a given list, counts successive equal elements and returns a list of pairs (value, count)?

Tags: sml, smlnj

I have to write a function in SML/NJ that in a given list, counts successive equal elements and returns a list of pairs (value, count). Function should look like this:

```
fun group (xs: ''a list): (''a * int) list
```

I can only use anonymous functions and the structures List, ListPair and Math.

I have no idea how to do it. Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple but inefficient way is to write [this version of `group`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53249501/235908):

```
val group : ''a list -> ''a list list
```

and transform the output further into:

```
val group_count : ''a list -> (''a * int) list
```

in the following way:

```
fun group_count xss = map (fn xs => (hd xs, length xs)) xss
```

But a more efficient way would be to write a function `span_count`:

```
fun span_count p x [] count = (count, [])
  | span_count p x (y::xs) count =
    if p (x, y)
    then span_count p x xs (count+1)
    else (count, y::xs)
```

and use it recursively:

```
fun group_count [] = []
  | group_count (x::xs) =
    case span_count op= x xs 1 of
      (count, ys) => (x, count) :: group_count ys
```